# Reduce scroll speed on scrollable year list to land on a year

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a project where it requires a scrollable year for filtering.

What I did is I made use of `overflow-y: auto;` and set the scrollbar background to transparent.

It is working, however, I think I need to reduce the scrolling speed so that each scroll will land on a year. Any idea how to do this?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sn-tin/pen/zYmgGMg

```js
let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
let startYear = 2013;
const yearContainer = document.querySelector(".years-list");

for (let i = startYear; i <= currentYear; i++) {
  const node = document.createElement("li");
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(i);
  node.classList.add("year");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  yearContainer.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.scrollable-year {
  position: relative;
}

.years-list {
  width: 284px;
  height: 115px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 45px 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #f2f5f6;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.year {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-top: ;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

.gradientTop,
.gradientBottom {
  width: 284px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
}

.gradientTop {
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    #fff 56.56%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.59) 83.65%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 86.25%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 99.98%,
    rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.24) 99.99%
  );
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.gradientBottom {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0.01%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 1.09%,
    #fff 46.74%
  );
  box-shadow: 0px -0.5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-year accordion-block">
    <h5 class='title'>Publishing Year</h5>
    <div class="gradientTop"></div>
    <ul class="years-list">
    </ul>
    <div class="gradientBottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe CSS scroll snap can help here, idk. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_scroll_snap

Comment: Do you only want to allow scrolling in the div? and what do you mean land on a year? Only one of the years should be shown?